# How to pass a value from one class to the main one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Lets say I have these two files:
`App.js` (the file that actually runs the program)

```
const App = () => {
    const [variable1, setVariable1] = useState(0);
    return (
    <NewFile />
    );
}
export default App;
```

`NewFile.js`

```
const NewFile = () => {
    const [partText, setPartText] = useState("");
    const [wholeText, setWholeText] = useState("");
    if (partText != "")
    {
       setWholeText(partText);
    }
 return (
    {wholeText}
    );
}
export default NewFile;
```

Now, here comes my question. How can I set `"variable1"` to be equal to `"wholeText"`? The most logical solution would be: `setVariable1(NewFile.wholeText)` and obviously it doesn't work like that. I have seen some solutions with `props` but from what I understood I can only pass the value from (in this case) `App.js` to `NewFile.js` because I am calling `NewFile.js` in `App.js`.

I might have understood props wrongly and there might be a simple way to do the opposite, but I really can't think of anything else for now.

Comment: Pass `setVariable1` down to `NewFile` using a prop.

Comment: The simplest thing is to pass both `variable1` and `setVariable1` to `NewFile`. Then they are literally the same state. Update in one component will also update the other.

Comment: you should pass the setter to the `NewFile` component as `<NewFile setVariable1={setVariable1}/>`

Comment: This is pretty good at explaining how props work https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Comment: And this one shows how your child component can react to an event and pass data via an event handler up to the parent https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events